# Adding a searchbar above a UITableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

How is a searchbar added above a UITableView? Would just the searchbar be enough or would the search bar and search display be chosen?

I want to redraw the tableview with the items that are found by the search.

Answer (score 8):

`UISearchDisplayController` is specifically designed to solve your problem. You should be able to figure out how to use it from reading the documentation.

Of course you could just handle the `UISearchBar` (or even `UITextField` if you want to build your own search bar) yourself.

Here's some code to get you started:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    searchController.delegate = self;
}
```

Pretty much all there's left to do is to implement the delegates. If you need any help with that let me know, but may I suggest you ask a new question for each problem you encounter a long the way. Of course if you leave a comment here I will take a look at it.